# Segmentation fault while running rails (diaspora)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, diaspora

I was trying to run [diaspora](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora) (social network build with rails) on my machine for testing. It's fedora 18 64bit, and I get this problem.

It's very big error track message, so I add it here.
https://gist.github.com/moemen/5832397

Comment: It looks like your Ruby is set to the 1.9 system one but your GEM_HOME points to your 2.0 Ruby. We do have .rvmrc, did you ignore? Did you try to reopen your shell and reentering your clone of the Diaspora? What messages do you get when doing so?

Comment: no messages appear and it didn't appear before !

Comment: Ensure the following line is in your `.bashrc`: `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`. If you had to add it, reopen your shell again.

Comment: I tried `/bin/bash --login` and a message appeared asking me to install ruby 1.9.3-p429. It seamed really to be versions conflict problem. Thank you :)